# Defining new language based on C++

Tags: adobe-brackets

I would like to add a new language (called 'kiwi') into [the Brackets code editor](http://brackets.io/)  which is based on C++. It uses the exact same rules but has additional keywords.

I've already done the part of adding the additional keywords with separate syntax highlighting directly on the `clike.js` file but i don't really like directly modifying the def for C++

Can someone explain to me how I can achieve this? I don't really understand the difference between using `def()` and `CodeMirror.defineMIME()`. If this new language  will take cpp/hpp input files, how will the editor switch from C++ -> kiwi?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have no idea what piece of software this is relating to.

Comment: This is the Brackets IDE from Adobe I am talking about, hope things are clear now

Comment: Thanks, +1, that clears it up.

Answer (score 1):

Patching your local copy of the code, as you've done, might be perfectly fine for your needs. (And if you [run from a Git copy of the source](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Hack-on-Brackets), it's easy to pull down updates without losing your local diffs).

If you want to do it a "cleaner" way, you can write a Brackets extension to define the new language - this way the change is easily shareable with others, and updating Brackets is even easier.

The way you'd do this roughly follows the [Defining a new language](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Language-Support#defining-a-new-language) docs:

- [Write an extension](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-write-extensions) to package up your code that will define the new language (below)
- The CM mode "clike" is already loaded, so you don't need to worry about that
- Call `CodeMirror.defineMIME()` to set up a clike configuration with the right list of keywords - using a new mimetype name of your choosing. (Looking at the `def()` code in clike.js, I don't think the extra stuff it does is especially relevant for Brackets).
- Call `LanguageManager.defineLanguage()` to tell Brackets about your new language mode (and what file extensions map to it, etc.). You should be able to mostly copy [how the C++ mode is defined here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/blob/master/src/language/languages.json#L109) - except with your new MIME name instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should read CodeMirror documentation to find out about writing your [modes](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#modeapi).

But in short you can define your own type of clike language, by using `CodeMirror.defineMIME()`.

You also asked what's the difference between `def()` and `CodeMirror.defineMIME()`. If you look at the code you can see that `def()` function is calling `CodeMirror.defineMIME()` at the end, so I believe it is just a more readable way of defining the type.

Also it seems that it's impossible to define more than one language on the same extension type (not 100% sure).